# Why doesn't ConcurrentHashMap return the value even though key.equals(k)?

Tags: java

I have a simple object I would like to use as a key in my HashMap.  MyObject is defined such that:

```
MyObject obj1 = new MyObject("some string");
MyObject obj2 = new MyObject("some string");
assertTrue(obj1.equals(obj2));
assertTrue(obj1.hashCode()==obj2.hashCode());
```

According to the doc for [ConcurrentHashMap.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)),

> if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that key.equals(k), 
>   then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null

However, if I try to use MyObject as the map key, retrieval fails:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<MyObject,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<MyObject,String>();
map.put(obj1,"test value");
String foundValue = map.get(obj2);
assertNotNull(foundValue);         //fails
```

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT**: as requested, here is a full running example:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class MyObject {
    String name = null;

    public MyObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean equals(MyObject otherObject) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (otherObject!=null) {
            if (getClass().equals(otherObject.getClass())) {
                if (name==null) {
                    if (otherObject.getName()==null)
                        result = true;
                } else if (name.equals(otherObject.getName()))
                    result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject obj1 = new MyObject("some string");
        MyObject obj2 = new MyObject("some string");
        if (obj1.equals(obj2) && obj1.hashCode()==obj2.hashCode()) {
            ConcurrentHashMap<MyObject,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<MyObject,String>();
            map.put(obj1,"test value");
            String foundValue = map.get(obj2);
            if (foundValue==null)
                System.out.println("get returned null");
            else
                System.out.println("get returned my string");
        } else {
            System.out.println("something's not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you also [override `hashCode()` in MyObject?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05273/)

Comment: @markspace yes.  I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: you'll have to show the code from `MyObject` then.  HashMap works, the problem must be somewhere else.  Show us the equals and hashCode methods you made.

Comment: Try replacing Objects.hash(name) with name.hashCode(). From the docs:  Warning: When a single object reference is supplied, the returned value does not equal the hash code of that object reference. This value can be computed by calling hashCode(Object).

Comment: @cecil23 if I do that, I need to check for null.  Objects.hash() is supposed to take care of that.  Regardless, I changed it and the outcome was the same.

Comment: Why are you concerned with checking for null? Do that check in the constructor. Also see edit in above comment re your misuse of Objects.hash().

Comment: @cecilg23 using name.hashCode() didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not overriden `equals`, you have instead created a new `equals` method with a different signature.

If you change

```
public boolean equals(MyObject otherObject) {
```

to

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
```

(and add appropriate casts), your code will work as expected.

You could have easily avoided that mistake by using the `@Override` annotation, which would have lead to a compilation error.

Comment: I implemented hashCode, and the hashCode for the two objects are equal

Comment: @datguy can you show a full example that compiles and reproduces your issue? The devil is often in the details...

Comment: That was a devilish little detail. Before casting, I assume I should check to make sure it's an instance of MyObject, correct?

Comment: @datguy yes and return false if not.